# How to Fix Conversion failed when converting the varchar value data type int

Tags: stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure that return a value with passing a parameter.

When I execute this stored procedure, this error occurs:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'AND GenderId=' to data type int.

My code:

```
create proc sp_getPatientRegistration (@genderId int) AS
declare @condition  varchar(500);
begin
If @genderId!=0
SET @condition='AND GenderId='+@genderId
    SELECT PtRegNo,Name,MobileNo,GenderId FROm tbl_PATIENT_REGISTRATION WHERE 1=1 +@condition
end
```

Expected result is shown in this screenshot:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdu5C.jpg)

Comment: You **MUST NOT** Capitalize Each And Every Single Word In The English Language!

Answer (score 0):

@genderId is a integer, you must convert it to varchar before concatenate it.
if you are using sql you can using:

```
CAST(@genderId as Nvarchar(50))
```